# Binding a service variable in component through return functions

Tags: angular, angular5

i want to bind a service variable with ngModel (2-way-binding) to a component input. Therefore i use simple return functions to return the service variable (This is needed to get the right variable from service).

But if i want to run this code i get following error:

```
Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 10 in [getName()=$event] in ng:///AppModule/HelloComponent.html@2:9 ("
{{nameService.name}}
```

Hello in my Case its more complex example. To simplify this i made following example and demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwgoux?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NameService {
  name:string="Hello World!";
  constructor() { }
  getName(){return this.name};
}
```

Component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NameService} from './name.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  {{nameService.name}}
  <input [(ngModel)]="getName()">`
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  constructor(private nameService:NameService){
  }
  getName(){
    return this.nameService.getName();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your template to handle the two-way data binding in the following way:

```
<input [ngModel]=getName() (ngModelChange)="setName($event)">
```

Where `setName` is a setter for your service variable.

I forked your stackblitz to show a simplified example of what you want to achieve: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k7opzq)

Comment: Same here. It throws no error, but service variable is not updated.(the local "name" variable was irritating and autogenerated from SB. I removed it from demo.

Comment: So you need to update the variable in the service when the user types  something in the input?

Comment: yes. I wanted to use ngModel. (I know ngModelChange  and setters are a possible solution)

Comment: I modified the answer, have a look at it